# Converting a List to data frame [problems]

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have converted a ped file to data frame then i filter some of the columns.

Next I wanted to know the unique values of the data frame.

My script is as following:

```
 df <- as.data.frame(ped)
 df2 <- df[,-1:-6]
 x <- sapply(df2, unique)
```

But my vector `x` is a list type object. 
I wanted to transform this list type object into a data frame with this script

`dfinal <- as.data.frame(x)`

The following error appears

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>   check.names = TRUE,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2,
>   1

I think the error could be that some values in the `x` list are different in number i.e.

```
SNP 1.1 : chr [1:3] "T" "C" "0"

SNP 1.2 : chr [1:3] "C" "G" "0"

SNP 1.3 : chr [1:2] "A" "T"
```

What I want is a data frame where the columns names are variables like `"A" "T" "C" "G" "0"` and the row names the `Snp1.1, SNP 1.2, ...`

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used `mtcars` to reproduce your problem. First I got the unique values, then turned each part of the list into a df, then stacked used`rbind` to get them into one df. Finally I turned row names into a column.

```
x <- sapply(mtcars, unique)

x2 <- lapply(x, data.frame)

x3 <- do.call(rbind,x2)

x3$names <- row.names(x3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, transfer list elements with different length is not possible, therefore; we will fill the gap using NAs

```
maxl <- max(sapply(x,length))
x <- sapply(df, unique) 

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lapply(x,function(y)c(y,rep(NA,maxl-length(y)))) %>% 
       bind_rows() %>% 
       gather(key,val) %>% 
       mutate(flag=1) %>% 
       spread(val,flag)

# A tibble: 3 x 7
   key     `0`     A     C     G     T `<NA>`
 <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 SNP1      1    NA     1    NA     1     NA
2 SNP2      1    NA     1     1    NA     NA
3 SNP3     NA     1    NA    NA     1      1
```

Provide reproducible "fake" data using `dput` is important for others to help you

```
df <- structure(list(SNP1 = c("T", "C", "0"), SNP2 = c("C", "G", "0"
  ), SNP3 = c("A", "T", "T")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```